# Oracle APEX: Scale image to screen

Tags: oracle, image, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I would like to scale an image that is saved in *Shared Components* so that the right side of it is exactly on the right end of the screen.

How is that possible?

I am using Oracle APEX 5.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming you are displaying the image in a Display Image page item.

In the item properties, under Advanced, set the Custom Attributes property to:

```
style="width: 100%"
```

This screenshot shows two Display Image items based on the same small picture (held as a static application file).  The second has the style property:

[image]
See [my demo page on apex.oracle.com](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=82795:33)

Alternatively, this could be done using CSS defined in a file or in page inline CSS like this:

```
#P123_MY_IMAGE_ITEM {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Or you could set the item's CSS Classes property to e.g. "full-width" and define the CSS as:

```
.full-width {
    width: 100%;
}
```

This is probably the best option if you will do this to many images.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Good.  I've updated my answer to show some alternative ways.